# The metric or topology between subsets of Euclidean space

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity, metric-spaces

$\newcommand{\ps}{\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^2)}$
Before asking a question, I would like to introduce a definition that motivated me. Consider the path-like function $f:[0, 1] \to \ps$ defined by

$$
\forall t \in [0,1]:f(t) = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^2~|~||x - (t,t)|| \le 1\}
$$

It is seemingly *continuous* in some sense (at least for me). The goal is to find a circumstance in which we can say that $f$ is continuous.

I tried to define a corresponding metric candidate $d: \ps \times \ps \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$
\forall P,Q \in \ps:d(P,Q) = \left\Vert\frac{1}{A(P)}\int_{P}(x,y)dxdy - \frac{1}{A(Q)}\int_{Q}(x,y)dxdy\right\Vert
$$
where $A(P)$ is the area of $P$, and each term side the norm represents the geometric center. But the function $d$ fails to be a metric because there are $P \neq Q$ such that $d(P,Q) = 0$.

Question) Can we find some metric or topology on $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ by which $f$ is continuous?

Comment: I think one trivial way is to identify $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the set of all unit discs in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 1):

> But the function $d$ fails to be a metric because there are $P \neq Q$ such that $d(P,Q) = 0$.

Note that you don't have to define a distance on all subsets of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. In fact you already restricted yourself to measurable sets. So I assume you can restrict yourself furthermore, since $f(t)$ is a very well behaving set for any $t$, namely: a closed ball. A good way to do this is to take $F(\mathbb{R}^n)$ which is the set of all compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. This makes things easier, although your concrete definition will not work for compact subsets as well. But I think it does work if we restrict ourselves even further, by considering closures of open bounded subsets.

But the classical [Hausdorff distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance):

$$d(P,Q)=\max\bigg\{\sup_{p\in P}d(p,Q), \sup_{q\in Q}d(P,q)\bigg\}$$

does work for $F(\mathbb{R}^n)$. In fact it is a metric on $F(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (or $F(M)$ for any metric space $M$). Otherwise it has a similar problem: $d(A,\overline{A})=0$.

---

In that situation assume that $x,y\in[0,1]$. Then I leave as an exercise that

$$d(f(x),f(y))=\lVert (x,x)-(y,y)\rVert=\sqrt{2}\cdot|x-y|$$

and so $f$ is not only continuous but also [Lipschitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity).

---

Note that there is also a different way to look at the problem. Instead of defining a metric on $\mathcal{P}(X)$ you can actually treat your $f$ as a multivalued mapping. In that scenario there are various different definitions of [hemicontinuity (upper and lower)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemicontinuity) that you can apply. They do correspond to topological continuity if so called Vietoris topology (upper and lower) is considered on whole $\mathcal{P}(X)\backslash\{\emptyset\}$, but in general that topoogy is not metrizable.

Comment: Thank you for your elaborated answer! I think I need some time to fully appreciate your answer... I am working on it :)